ALIX with OpenWRT keeps restarting
I've got problem with ALIX 2D3 (or 2D13) which keeps restarting. It reboots in different period of time - from 2 to every 20 minutes. What we did is changed DC adapter but it's still looks the same.
In logread I saw that there's kernel warnings like below:
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.893550] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.898990] Modules linked in: pppoe ppp_async pppox ppp_generic nf_conntrack_ipv6 iptable_nat ipt_REJECT ipt_MASQUERADE xt_time xt_tcpudp xt_tcpmss xt_statistic xt_state xt_recent xt_nat xt_multiport xt_mark xt_mac xt_limit xt_length xt_hl xt_helper xt_ecn xt_dscp xt_conntrack xt_connmark xt_connlimit xt_connbytes xt_comment xt_TCPMSS xt_REDIRECT xt_LOG xt_HL xt_FLOWOFFLOAD xt_DSCP xt_CT xt_CLASSIFY slhc r8169 nf_reject_ipv4 nf_nat_redirect nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_log_ipv4 nf_flow_table_hw nf_flow_table nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack_rtcache nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_filter ipt_ECN ip_tables e1000e crc_ccitt i2c_dev ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 nf_log_common ip6table_mangle ip6table_filter ip6_tables x_tables igb i2c_algo_bit
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.969737]  e1000 tun button_hotplug ptp pps_core mii
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.974913] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Not tainted 4.14.95 #0
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.980939] Hardware name: PC Engines APU2/APU2, BIOS 4.0.7 02/28/2017
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.987485] task: ffff88811a0c8000 task.stack: ffffc90000068000
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.993422] RIP: 0010:0xffffffff81802003
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  306.997361] RSP: 0018:ffff88811ed03ca0 EFLAGS: 00010202
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.002613] RAX: 0000ffff00000001 RBX: ffff888118203b00 RCX: 0000000000000003
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.009763] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff888118203b00 RDI: ffff888118203b00
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.016913] RBP: ffff88811ed03d20 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.024064] R10: ffff88811930d600 R11: ffff88811ed03cc8 R12: ffffffff81c6e200
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.031214] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8881185f8000 R15: 0000000000000008
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.038365] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88811ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.046479] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.052236] CR2: 00007fa629d90000 CR3: 0000000117cb2000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.059378] Call Trace:
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.061850]  <IRQ>
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.063884]  ? 0xffffffff814ff6cb
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.067216]  0xffffffff814fef32
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.070385]  ? 0xffffffff814fcb84
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.073730]  0xffffffff814fed9d
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.076893]  0xffffffff814ff1b1
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.080066]  ? 0xffffffff814feb30
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.083401]  0xffffffff814c3167
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.086555]  ? 0xffffffff8127efef
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.089887]  ? 0xffffffffa0046976 [igb@ffffffffa003e000+0x20000]
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.095919]  0xffffffff814c4d44
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.099076]  ? 0xffffffff814c4d44
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.102406]  0xffffffff814c5231
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.105560]  0xffffffff814c7d53
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.108724]  0xffffffff818000ba
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.111879]  0xffffffff81084492
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.115040]  0xffffffff816020c4
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.118196]  0xffffffff81600941
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.121351]  </IRQ>
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.123464] RIP: 0010:0xffffffff815c9486
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.127400] RSP: 0018:ffffc9000006be20 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff6d
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.134987] RAX: 0000000080000000 RBX: ffff88811a2c1400 RCX: ffff88811ed00000
Mon May 27 10:50:12 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  307.142138] RDX: 4ec4ec4ec4ec4ec5 RSI: 0000000000000034 RDI: ffff88811a2c1464

And second one:
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.659020] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.664455] Modules linked in: pppoe ppp_async pppox ppp_generic nf_conntrack_ipv6 iptable_nat ipt_REJECT ipt_MASQUERADE xt_time xt_tcpudp xt_tcpmss xt_statistic xt_state xt_recent xt_nat xt_multiport xt_mark xt_mac xt_limit xt_length xt_hl xt_helper xt_ecn xt_dscp xt_conntrack xt_connmark xt_connlimit xt_connbytes xt_comment xt_TCPMSS xt_REDIRECT xt_LOG xt_HL xt_FLOWOFFLOAD xt_DSCP xt_CT xt_CLASSIFY slhc r8169 nf_reject_ipv4 nf_nat_redirect nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_log_ipv4 nf_flow_table_hw nf_flow_table nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_conntrack_rtcache nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_filter ipt_ECN ip_tables e1000e crc_ccitt i2c_dev ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 nf_log_common ip6table_mangle ip6table_filter ip6_tables x_tables igb i2c_algo_bit
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.735128]  e1000 tun button_hotplug ptp pps_core mii
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.740304] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 4.14.95 #0
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.746329] Hardware name: PC Engines APU2/APU2, BIOS 4.0.7 02/28/2017
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.752883] task: ffff88811a0c8b80 task.stack: ffffc90000070000
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.758819] RIP: 0010:0xffffffff81802003
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.762757] RSP: 0018:ffff88811ed83ca0 EFLAGS: 00010202
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.768003] RAX: 0000ffff00000001 RBX: ffff8881182a6f00 RCX: 0000000000000003
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.775155] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8881182a6f00 RDI: ffff8881182a6f00
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.782311] RBP: ffff88811ed83d20 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.789462] R10: ffff888119931c00 R11: ffff88811ed83cc8 R12: ffffffff81c6e200
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.796613] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff888118a14000 R15: 0000000000000008
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.803766] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88811ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.811868] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.817635] CR2: 00007ffcdada17e8 CR3: 0000000117c4a000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.824778] Call Trace:
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.827245]  <IRQ>
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.829273]  ? 0xffffffff814ff6cb
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.832608]  0xffffffff814fef32
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.835773]  ? 0xffffffff814fcb84
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.839102]  0xffffffff814fed9d
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.842265]  0xffffffff814ff1b1
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.845418]  ? 0xffffffff814feb30
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.848747]  0xffffffff814c3167
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.851912]  ? 0xffffffff8127efef
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.855252]  ? 0xffffffffa0046976 [igb@ffffffffa003e000+0x20000]
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.861272]  0xffffffff814c4d44
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.864434]  ? 0xffffffff814c4d44
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.867761]  0xffffffff814c5231
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.870916]  0xffffffff814c7d53
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.874080]  0xffffffff818000ba
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.877234]  0xffffffff81084492
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.880387]  0xffffffff816020c4
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.883543]  0xffffffff81600941
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.886697]  </IRQ>
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.888811] RIP: 0010:0xffffffff8146ba36
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.892747] RSP: 0018:ffffc90000073e98 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff6d
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.900336] RAX: ffff88811ed9f340 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 000000000000001f
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.907483] RDX: 00000076aa0a82a4 RSI: 00000000803d7d59 RDI: 0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.914640] RBP: ffffc90000073ec8 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 000000000001eb80
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.921790] R10: ffffc90000073e68 R11: 00000076a8db05a3 R12: ffff88811a1b3400
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.928942] R13: 00000076aa0a82a4 R14: ffffffff81c45498 R15: 0000000000000000
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.936096]  ? 0xffffffff8146ba0e
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.939426]  0xffffffff8146bae2
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.942588]  0xffffffff810ac303
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.945741]  0xffffffff810ac4a0
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.948898]  0xffffffff810ac67f
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.952053]  0xffffffff8103e2e0
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.955215]  0xffffffff810000d5
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.958369] Code: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f ae e8 <ff> e0 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 2e
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.alert kernel: [  509.977416] RIP: 0xffffffff81802003 RSP: ffff88811ed83ca0
Mon May 27 10:27:30 2024 kern.warn kernel: [  509.982866] ---[ end trace 153cf72ba0b5f885 ]---

What I also see is named daemon keeps informing me about permission denied when resolving names:
Mon May 27 10:48:56 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'pdns196.ultradns.info/A/IN': 2610:a1:1016::e8#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'extensions.gnome.org/A/IN': 2620:52:3:1:5054:ff:fec7:bbd0#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'extensions.gnome.org/A/IN': 2620:52:3:1:5054:ff:fe90:282b#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'extensions.gnome.org/AAAA/IN': 2620:52:3:1:5054:ff:fec7:bbd0#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2607:feb8::5:8#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2001:470:1f1d:244::44#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2001:678:4::16#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2001:678:5::16#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2001:470:1f07:d0b::22#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/AAAA/IN': 2001:678:5::16#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.axu.tm/A/IN': 2001:1430:a:35::35#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:14b8:188d::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:708:10:53::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:678:4::e#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:67c:1010:6::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:678:e:104::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:500:14:6098:ad::1#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:678:a0::aaaa#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:678:a0::aaaa#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:678:20::30#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:678:20::30#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2a01:3f0:0:302::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2a01:3f0:0:302::53#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2620:10a:80ac::190#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2620:10a:80ac::190#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:678:4::e#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:500:14:6098:ad::1#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns3.he.net/A/IN': 2001:470:100::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns3.he.net/A/IN': 2001:470:200::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns3.he.net/A/IN': 2001:470:500::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns3.he.net/A/IN': 2001:470:300::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns3.he.net/A/IN': 2001:470:400::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'puck.nether.net/A/IN': 2001:728:1808::4#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'puck.nether.net/A/IN': 2001:500:14:6004:ad::1#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'puck.nether.net/A/IN': 2602:fe55:5::5#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:678:5::26#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2620:10a:80ec::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2001:67c:2b0:15::35#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/AAAA/IN': 2620:10a:80eb::2#53
Mon May 27 10:48:57 2024 daemon.info named[3659]: permission denied resolving 'ns.trex.fi/A/IN': 2001:678:5::26#53

Is it somehow conneted? I don't have ALIX device to switch it so maybe someone has similiar problem?

No, this is not connected.
First two ones hint that either your hardware is faulty or some kernel module has bugs. Frequent and unexpected restarts also hint at that. You have to actually evaluate these traces to know for sure.
DNS permission denied has absolutely nothing to do with that.
